# Holomorphic map from a neighborhood in $\mathbb C$ to S^3

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Does there exist a holomorphic map from a neighborhood of $\mathbb C$ to $S^3 \subseteq \mathbb C^2$?

Comment: Please do double check your typing: the title is the very first thing people see of your question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose such a map exists and is non-constant. Let $f,g$ be its components. By composing the map with a holomorphic function on the right and with an element of $U(2)$ on the left, we can assume that in a neighborhood of 0 we have $f(z)=z$ (i.e., we can take $f$ as a local coordinate) and $g(z)=1+az+\cdots$ with $a\neq 0$. Now let $b$ be a complex number such that $Re(ab)\neq 0$ and set $h(t)=bt, t\in\mathbb{R}$. Then on the curve given by $t\mapsto h(t)$ the equation $|f|^2+|g|^2=1$ becomes $$b^2t^2+1+2Re(ab)t+ o(t)=1,$$ which should hold for all $t$ sufficiently close to 0. This is impossible.

upd: this argument generalizes to maps $\mathbb{C}\to S^{2n-1},n>2$ and also implies the following "generalized maximum principle": for a holomorphic map $f:D\to\mathbb{C}^n,D\subset \mathbb{C}$ connected and contained in the closure of its interior, the maximum of $|f|$ can't be attained in an interior point, unless $f$ is constant. To see this one can notice that the moduli of the components of $f$ are subharmonic, so their sum, $|f|^2$, satisfies the maximum principle.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, such a map exists, and any such map has to be a map to a point in $\mathbb S^3$, because has to sends any holomorphic curve in the neighbourhood of $\mathbb C$ to a holomorphic curve in $S^3$, but $S^3$ does not contain any holomorphic curve (since the distribution of complex directions in $S^3$ is non-integrable).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The following is *incorrect*:

"Yes, but on each connected subset of the domain, the map will need to be constant; this follows from the maximum modulus principle."

Comment: Christopher -- could you perhaps elaborate on how exactly you apply the maximum modulus principle to this? 

Comment: If the map, say $f(z)$, sends to $S^3$, then the modulus of the map is constant. So then $|f(z)|$ is maximized on some interior point $z_0$; the maximum modulus principle states that a holomorphic map satisfying this must be constant.

Comment: Given that the domain is connected, of course. Otherwise, $f(z)$ can assume a different constant for each of its connected components.

Comment: Christopher -- I was just wondering whether you were applying the 1-dimensional version of the maximum principle. I agree that the 2-dimensional version also holds, but is it possible to prove it without first proving that there are no non-constant functions $\mathbb{C}\to S^3$?

Comment: The maximum modulus principle relies on the open mapping property for holomorphic functions, so were to have learned complex analysis all over again, I would probably encounter this result first before encountering the $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow S^3$ result.

Comment: Christopher -- how exactly do you deduce the maximum modulus principle for maps $\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}^2$ from the open mapping property?

Comment: Let $U$ be an open neighborhood. Suppose that $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $U$ and $|f(z)|$ is maximized at $p \in U$. If $f$ is non-constant, then $f$ is an open map, hence $f(U)$ is open, hence there is an open neighborhood of $f(p)$ contained in $f(U)$, hence there are points in $f(U)$ such that $|f(z)| > |f(p)|$, a contradiction. Therefore $f$ is constant. 

Comment: Christopher -- are you in fact talking about the maximum principle for maps from $\mathbb{C}$ to $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: This should hold for any holomorphic map $\mathbb{C} \rightarrow B$, where $B$ is a Banach space over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Christopher -- ok but none of such maps is open unless $dim B=1$.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just realized that only a much weaker result holds. I retract my response

Comment: At least for the case $B = \mathbb{C}^2$, the result appears to hold, according to the following:

http://www.jstor.org/stable/2035432

Comment: Christopher -- the argument in Dmitri's answer or mine shows that it holds for any $B=\mathbb{C}^n$; I've edited my answer to include that. In the paper you cite there are references to proofs for general $B$.